# show JSON in new window

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a problem with json. I'd like to display the result of my form in the new browser window in JSON. (When user fills all fields in the form, button becomes enabled and shows JSON in specified format (I did it)). I translated it in JSON but dunno how to output it...I'm thinking of create new html page and do window.open on button on 1st page, but then it doesn't read data from 1st page which user entered. Or should I save it somehow in JSON file and then read it from other page?
For example:

```
<form name="form" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<label> <b> * Date: </b> </label> <input type="datetime-local" ng-model="date"        name="date" onkeyup="changeButtonStatus()" onchange="changeButtonStatus()" required>    </input>
<button type="submit" id="btn" class="btn" disabled="disabled">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I have some form with date field and button:

I can easily get JSON of date field by {{date | json}} on the same page, but I just want to output it in new browser window. How can I do this? Please help me with some tips. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to use Dialog?

Comment: Like alternative. But main target is still new browser window.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not too big you can send the information to the new window as a data URL.

The frame will be reused once it is open.

This might be a start, showing how to plug in the JSON data and break it up over multiple lines for display.

```
window.open('data:application/json,'
    +JSON.stringify(location).replace(/([[{,])/g, "$1%0a"),
    'jsonFrame',
    'resizeable,top=100, left=100, height=200, width=300,status=1')
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open) for all the details.

Comment: To be honest it's big enough. But still thanks :] Tried that out but it doesn't read {{date | json}}

Comment: What is {{date | json}}, some kind of templating?
Try the updated example, which shows how to plug in your JSON data

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get at the window.opener from the new window and parse values out of it. The following plunker shows storing data from the current scope in an accessible area when the controller's submit is clicked. From the new window it then parses the content from the opener into the window's scope for further processing.

http://plnkr.co/edit/OkKX5zxYVSoZ7w81WV8J?p=preview

You'll notice here too how to get an angular friendly way of calling the submission and the disabling of the button until ready.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

How about to save your input data into a cookie on one page and then get it via JavaScript when you will open a new window? 
I could prepare the code in jsFiddle, but seems like it does not import external resources at this moment. So I'll post it here:

page 1:

```
...
<form name="form" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <label> <b> * Date: </b> </label> <input id="date" type="datetime-local" ng-model="date"        name="date" onkeyup="changeButtonStatus()" onchange="changeButtonStatus()" required> </input>
    <button id="btn" class="btn" >Submit</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btn').click( function() {

       var cookie_value = $('#inut_test').val();
       /*cookie_value  should be your json string*/
       $.cookie("json_cookie", cookie_value, { path: '/' });

       window.open("http://localhost/page2");

       return false;
    });
</script>
...
```

page 2:

```
...
<a id="see-cookie" href="#">
    click me!!!
</a>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#see-cookie').live('click', function() {
        alert($.cookie('json_cookie'));
        return false;
     });
</script>
...
```

Do not forget about `{ path: '/' }` cookie property to set it for all site and about including jQuery cookie library into your page.